# Beginner's TextMate Question

Tags: textmate

So I'm coming from the world of Visual Studio wherein which I have "intellisense" and certain keyboard shortcuts (thanks also in large part to ReSharper). I am transitioning to the Mac and have a copy of TextMate.

How do you get it to automatically place a closing HTML tag when you create a new one? Is this a "bundle" and if so how do I get it to work.

Sorry, beginner's question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are in HTML mode... (look at the status bar at the bottom)...

Type a word then press ctrl <

That will use the word to create open and close tags for the word (e.g. table)

```
table^<
<table></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Tab trigger" snippets from the HTML bundle (installed by default).  For example, if you want a `body` tag, you can type:

```
body[TAB]
```

and TextMate will insert the full opening and closing tag.

For more on the various HTML bundle capabilities (because there are several) see http://manual.macromates.com/en/bundles#html

Comment: Tabbing only works for certain html tags that are predefined in textmate, like body and table.

Comment: Thus the mention of the '"Tab trigger" snippets from the HTML bundle'. I suppose, though, that's a good thing to clarify to someone who is new to TextMate.